# Jenkins Dynamic parameters based on previously selected parameter value

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

Here I am basically looking for a dependency parameter.

Let's say I have two dropdowns in the build parameter section. Based on the value selected from the first dropdown the possible default 
I want the values of the second dropdown to vary.

Is there any plugin or approach to handle this requirement effectively?

Comment: If I want the second dropdown to take values from the output of a shell script how do i do that?

Answer (score 15):

This is exactly what you are looking for:
https://github.com/biouno/uno-choice-plugin/wiki/Uno-Choice-Cascade-Dynamic-Choice-Parameter

It seems to be a hidden gem, haven't found it in any of the similar questions so far.

Comment: Perhaps a bit late but if anyone else needs this, as noted in [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393671/how-to-get-a-parameter-depend-of-other-parameter-in-hudson-or-jenkins) the plugin was shared with the Jenkins community and _officially_ renamed to [Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin)

Answer (score 10):

Let's keep thing simple, Here is Step by Step process to achieve the required.
1.Install Active Choices Plugin in your Jenkins.
2.Add an ACTIVE CHOICE PARAMETER
[image]

3. Add an ACTIVE CHOICE REACTIVE PARAMETER.
   [image]

4.Click on apply and then on save.
Its done. !!!
 Do comment if facing any problem with this.

Answer (score 5):

I have not used it, but it looks like the following plugin may do what you want:

A Jenkins parameter plugin that allows for two select elements. The second select populates values depending upon the selection made for the first select.

https://github.com/tekante/Dynamic-Jenkins-Parameter/wiki

Comment: *Seems* to be quite limited, allows just two choices in the first drop-down, so only two alternative lists for 2nd drop-down.

Comment: Its Possible execute Groovy in this plugin?

Answer (score 5):

A new plugin with this capability (and much more) is available here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin

The wiki page contains several usage examples and code

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/file/n3321631/hudson.jpg) is what you want to achieve right?

Then you could inherit `hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition`, and override its method of `getChoicesText`. return the options based on whatever you want, in your situation, you could get environments from `Hudson.getInstance()`.

Below snippets is shown how get environment variable.

```
Hudson.getInstance().getGlobalNodeProperties()
       .get(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class).getEnvVars().get(name);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987368/how-to-make-dynamic-drop-down-lists-on-parameterized-build-page-in-a-custom-huds) is the similar question.

Comment: The question is about altering the list based on a parameter on the same form. I'm not sure if there is an easy to way achieve this, but I'd love to see some example code about how to do it. The way you (and the linked answer) show uses already existing information defined elsewhere, it's not altering choices dynamically based on another drop-down in the same form.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick it lets you to single select, multiselect and do it in levels
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example, I'd like to find when I was looking for this question ;

Here is the way to create an active choice reactive parameter with Jenkins job DSL.

```
activeChoiceReactiveParam('PARAMETER_NAME') {
    description('Parameter description')
    filterable()
    choiceType('SINGLE_SELECT')
    groovyScript {
        script('return [ANOTHER_PARAMETER + ".suffix", ANOTHER_PARAMETER + ".suffix2"]')
        fallbackScript('return ["NotFound"]')
    }
    referencedParameter('ANOTHER_PARAMETER')
}
```

Note: if it doesn't work by importing job via DSL, just "Configure" and "Save". There is a bug: [JENKINS-42655](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42655?focusedCommentId=378843&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-378843)