# How to get a parameter depend of other parameter in Hudson or Jenkins

Tags: parameters, jenkins, hudson

I have a problems with Hudson because my job needs two params for build
the first specifies the environment and can be one of DEV, QA, PROD,
and the second is a specific server, this parameter depends on the first one.

By example if I chose environment DEV, the second parameter can be only DEV1,DEV2, MAQ1
.
I don't have an idea if a plugin with this functionality exists  or I need to make something with groovy. I do not know please help me.

Thank you

Comment: What does environment mean here? How do you get the environment you choose in step 2?

Comment: This it's the question, i have 2 parameters and the second parameter depend of the first parameter, if you wan forget the paramateres names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that Jenkins loads the list of parameters to select when you open the "build project" page. There's no callback happening when selecting a parameter either.

In that case it will be difficult to restrict the second parameter based on the first one without javascript and a custom plugin.

I also looked at those:

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin
- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+Script+plugin
- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin

I would ask the jenkins user list for more information.

Comment: i think this is not correct as of 2020. i am using 'Active Choices Reactive Parameter' plugin to use previous parameter value - for example: 0param-type in drive;1param - select folder;2param-select subfolder;3param-select file and show content; - 3 active ch.prm used. the only limitation - you have to use `Groovy Script`

Answer (score 20):

Try [Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin). It is the second name of Uno-Choice  plugin, but it is located in official Jenkins repository and does not require UpdateSites Manager plugin. (Both plugins have the same author). Plugin has a great documentation with examples (and gif-demonstration) on the plugin's description page.

Comment: The plug-in started as Uno Choice (see @thenaglecode reply), then we decided to share with every Jenkins user. The community voted for a rename, and Ioannis suggested Active Choices, which was well accepted. The documentation and gifs, also kudos to Ioannis for that :-)

Comment: How do I implement the second Active Choice to use the value from the first Active Choice? I asked the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68728962/groovy-script-to-implement-how-to-get-a-parameter-depend-of-other-parameter-in

Answer (score 12):

A good plugin (requires you to have the [UpdateSites Manager](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/UpdateSites+Manager+plugin) plugin and register the [biouno update site](http://biouno.org/jenkins-update-site.html)) is the [uno-choice plugin](https://github.com/biouno/uno-choice-plugin) ( and friends).

The [Uno-Choice Cascade Dynamic Parameter Plugin](https://github.com/biouno/uno-choice-plugin/wiki/Uno-Choice-Cascade-Dynamic-Choice-Parameter) plugin allows for not only more than two levels of dependencies, but can generate dynamic content for the parameters which depend on previous input using either scriptler or inline groovy.

This is certainly *much more* capable than the previous answers.

Comment: looks like the Uno-Choice plugin is now the Active Choices plugin. See @kool79 's answer and comment by plugin author.

Answer (score 3):

For all of you who stumble upon the same kind of problem (like I did). There is a fairly new Jenkins plugin available that does exactly what is desired here: display a dependent set of drop-downs, updating dependent boxes when a main box changes selection.

[image: Dependent drop-down box example]

For your job you just need to follow the following steps:

#### Install "Multiselect Parameter Plugin"

The "multiselect parameter plugin" can be installed from Jenkins plugin management, the documentation is available [on its Jenkins Plugin page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/multiselect-parameter/).

#### Add new parameter

1. Use "Multiselect Parameter" type
2. Set name to a sensible value
3. give a short description
4. configure like shown below:

```
H,Environment,Machine
V,SELECTED_ENVIRONMENT,SELECTED_MACHINE
T,Development,
C,DEV,DEV1
T,Development,
C,DEV,DEV2
T,Quality Assurance,
C,QA,QA1
T,Quality Assurance,
C,QA,QA2
T,Quality Assurance,
C,QA,QA3
T,Production,
C,PROD,Machine1
T,Production,
C,PROD,Machine2
```

#### Use selected values

When you run "build with parameters" in your job, the following boxes are displayed for selection:

[image: Build parameter drop-downs matching the sample project screens]

In your build script you can simply use the configured environment variables `SELECTED_ENVIRONMENT` and `SELECTED_MACHINE`, which contain the selected values from both select boxes. The "human readable names" configured in `T`-prefixes rows of CSV configuration are only displayed in select boxes, you still get the technical names like `DEV` and `PROD` passed into the environment variables.

Comment: Great plugin! It is possible to declare it in Jenkinsfile properties parameters section? Or somehow to pass values to it using Groovy script?

Comment: Hi @RenatZaripov! I have not yet tried, actually. You would probably not want to use CSV to configure it in that case, would you? Maybe a more Groovy-like style, more object oriented? I may add that functionality if you need it?

Comment: Hi @sebastian-westemeyer, you right, CSV is good, but static. I think if in configure field will be added option to use Groovy, it make plugin even more flexible. In my case, for example I'm pass two columns one with branches and second with commits. And I can pick with your plugin the branch and one of commit in this branch to start build. Very handy! If groovy will be added, I can to do request data from external source via REST API. If you can add Groovy support in future versions, I will be happy! Thank you for quick responce and great plugin!

Comment: Hi @RenatZaripov! Would you care to try out a snapshot version of the plugin? I have evaluated the possibility to configure the multiselect boxes during a pipeline step and it looks promising so far. I could probably provide a test version as a download in a few days if you like. Sorry it took me so long but I had a few other projects to complete.

Comment: Hi @sebastian-westemeyer! Sure, I would love to test the new version of the plugin! Tell me how to get it, I'd be happy to try it and give feedback. I'm actually impressed, I didn't think you could get the new functionality ready so quickly.

Comment: Okay @RenatZaripov, here you go. Download the zip file from [westemeyer.de](http://download.westemeyer.de/multiselect-parameter-snapshot.zip). Inside the zip file you will find the hpi plugin file and an example Jenkinsfile. I am afraid it is a little bit more complicated to understand how to configure the tree style way. If you need any help, just let me know.

Comment: Hi @sebastian-westemeyer! Sorry for long response. Today I was tested plugin and this is awesome! Really easy to add new items, I like it! I want to say thank you for your job, result is exactly what I want!

Comment: Hello @RenatZaripov! I have finally released a new plugin version including the pipeline feature. Took a little longer because I also added a bunch of tests and some documentation.

Comment: Cheers @sebastian-westemeyer! Congratulations, that's amazing work, thank you so much, you did great!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).

First you put the first parameter into a settings file.Then the plugin can read from the file .Step two,generate the second parameter with your own script.

Comment: Thanks Johnny, i can read the parameter from a file, but the problem is: the script only execute when the paramater page is load, and not when i change then value of the value.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problems. I have a parameter for the environment Dev1, Dev2, ..... and a second one for the server where I need to run the job. I can compute the second from the first, but then the job is already running and I can't move it to another server anymore.

So I ended up having the two parameters with all possible choices and teaching the users to only choose the valid combinations. I can test during script execution whether the combination is valid. I also put a small html table in the comment of one of the parameters which contains valid combinations.

In your case, can you compute the value of the first parameter from the values of the second parameters? Then you would be able to compute (if still necessary) the value of the first parameter, write it to a temporary properties file and load it with the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) in a later build step.