# Accessing Jenkins job parameter variable in Extensible Choice using System Groovy Choice Parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm using [Extensible choice](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin) to define two parameters: `NEXT_CHANGE` and `NEXT_RELEASE` as follow:

[image]

but when i tried to use `NEXT_CHANGE` variable in `NEXT_RELEASE` groovy script it doesn't work. i tried both these methods with no success:

```
def hardcoded_param = "NEXT_CHANGE" 
def resolver = build.buildVariableResolver 
def hardcoded_param_value = resolver.resolve(hardcoded_param)
return [hardcoded_param_value]
```

and

```
def thr = Thread.currentThread() 
def build = thr?.executable 
def envVarsMap = build.parent.builds[0].properties.get("envVars")
eturn [envVarsMap.get('NEXT_CHANGE')]
```

any thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use this plugin in wrong way. Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393671/how-to-get-a-parameter-depend-of-other-parameter-in-hudson-or-jenkins) and its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26007906/4311135)

Comment: that's exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: How do i get the choices as a list of strings in my jenkins job ?