# Parameterized Jenkins job with dependent parameter

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to create a Jenkins job that has dependent parameters.

Firstly I want to be able to choose a main parameter: [image]
And then secondly to be able to choose from a set of options that are dependent parameters of the main parameter. [image]

If I select a different main parameter: [image]

I then want to have a different set of options as the dependencies to the second main parameter. [image]

Please, can you help me with how I can achieve this?

Comment: You may want to check out a new Jenkins plugin you could use to achieve your goal. Please have a look at my answer below ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest the [Active Choices plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice) (also known as "uno-choice"). ([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393671) has [references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31616498) to [both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26007906), though they're not the accepted answer.)

For your specific use case, you'll want to add two parameters to your job:

1. **Active Choices Parameter**

   - **Name**: MainOption
   - **Script**: Groovy Script

     ```
     return ['A','B']
     ```
2. **Active Choices Reactive Parameter**

   - **Name**: DependentOption
   - **Script**: Groovy Script

     ```
     def choices
     switch(MainOption){
         case 'A':
             choices = ['Blue','Green','Yellow']
             break
         case 'B':
             choices = ['Black','White','Grey']
             break
         default:
             choices = ['N/A']
             break
     }
     return choices
     ```
   - **Fallback Script**: Groovy Script

     ```
     return ['Option error']
     ```
   - **Referenced parameters**:

     ```
     MainOption
     ```

The "Referenced parameters" setting is the key - when that value is changed, the plugin will re-evaluate the Groovy script, giving you the dependent parameter effect.

Answer (score 3):

For all of you who stumble upon the same kind of problem (like I did). There is a fairly new Jenkins plugin available that does exactly what is desired here: display a dependent set of drop-downs, updating dependent boxes when a main box changes selection.

[image: Dependent drop-down box example]

For your job you just need to follow the following steps:

#### Install "Multiselect Parameter Plugin"

The "multiselect parameter plugin" can be installed from Jenkins plugin management, the documentation is available [on its Jenkins Plugin page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/multiselect-parameter/).

#### Add new parameter

1. Use "Multiselect Parameter" type
2. Set name to a sensible value
3. give a short description
4. configure like shown below:

```
H,Main option,Dependent option
V,SELECTED_MAIN,SELECTED_DEPENDENT
C,A,Blue
C,A,Green
C,A,Yellow
C,B,Black
C,B,White
C,B,Grey
```

#### Use selected values

When you run "build with parameters" in your job, the following boxes are displayed for selection:

[image: Build parameter drop-downs matching the sample project screens]

In your build script you can simply use the configured environment variables `SELECTED_MAIN` and `SELECTED_DEPENDENT`, which contain the selected values from both select boxes.