# Jenkins reactive choice parameter selection of values

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a choice parameter with values say:
A
B
BOTH

In above,

1. if i select "A", there should be one input box which should appear in the job parameter page to take value for A alone
2. if i select "B", there should be one input box which should appear in the job parameter page to take value for B alone
3. if i select "BOTH", there should be two input boxes which should appear in the job parameter page to take value for A & B values.

In the declarative script, i should print the values entered in the input boxes respectively. How to achieve this?

Comment: Any input on this usecase?

Answer (score 0):

Similar but not the same question was answered here [Parameterized Jenkins job with dependent parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845050/parameterized-jenkins-job-with-dependent-parameter)

Here is how you can parameterize your job:

1. Add an active choices parameter
   [image]
2. Add an active choices reactive reference parameter
   [image]
   2.1. and choose **Choice Type** and **Referenced parameters** as follows
   [image]
3. Implement pipeline script
   [image]
4. Build with parameters and enter values into input fields
   [image]
5. Here is the build output

[image]