# Jenkins parameterized job with dependent parameters

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, devops, jenkins-groovy

I have a parameterized job with 3 parameters. Once one of them has been chosen, the second one must be set to a disabled state.
Example:
If a **build_target** parameter is set to "Package", the **tests_set** parameter must be disabled entirely. But if the **build_target** parameter is in a default state "Service", the **tests_set** parameter must be presented as active.

Moreover, If the **deployment_options** parameter is not equal "Deploy to Develop", then each of the other parameters must be disabled.
[image]

Comment: See following questions with similar use cases
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51866184/10721630
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69018802/10721630

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can benefit from the [Active Choices Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/), have a look there. There's also [a good article covering](https://devopscube.com/declarative-pipeline-parameters/) its usage.